# Using localhost with Flutter & testing with iOS device

Tags: ios, node.js, flutter, localhost

I'm trying to figure out how to have an iOS device reach my node server from flutter. Node is listening on port 5000, and as you can see in my request is trying port 5000. Currently, I'm getting back a network error 'Connection refused, errno = 61'. Any idea how to fix it?

```
var url = 'http://localhost:5000/photo';

try {
  final res = await http.post(
    url,
    body: {'photo': photo, 'dir': destination},
    headers: {"Accept": "*/*", "Connection": "keep-alive"},
  );
  print(res.body);
  if (res.statusCode >= 400) {
    final resBody = json.decode(res.body);
    throw HttpException(resBody['errors'][0]);
  }
} catch (err) {
  throw (err);
}
```

Comment: use your pc ip, localhost is calling the device localhost instead of the node server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use your computer ip

- for windows you can run ipconfig
- for linux you can run ifconfig
- for mac you can run Ipconfig

Comment: Okay. I ran 'Ifconfig' in the terminal and found the line containing my IP. I used that as the address for node like this: http://{{my.ip.address}}:5000/photo, and that worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

instead of localhost use your computer's ip and your iOS device must by on the same network as the computer.